# Salesforce Communities: Self Register Error

Tags: community, error, customer-portal, user-registration

We want to enable users to self register to the community but this error is displayed upon clicking the Sign Up button:

> **Your request cannot be processed at this time. The site administrator
>   has been alerted.**

I have double checked that:

- The community is published.
- The Account Owner have a User Role assigned.
- The site guest user does have Create and Read permissions on the 
  Account and Contact objects.
- Self-registration is enabled for the community.

The error received in the email is:

> **There was an error in registering a user in site [Community Name]. The error message is: DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): User, original object: Contact.**

All of this is out of the box functionality. Apex and Visualforce Pages are also not modified. We are using the **Community Builder Page > Register** - not the Default Page for Self-Register.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The error means you are updating setup and non setup object in the same transaction so you get this error. Weird thing is you are just hitting the sign up button and you get this error. Can you increase logs for site guest user and see whats wrong in logs?

Comment: I tried using debug logs but nothing will be logged since external users are the ones who are trying to sign up. Do you have other ideas on why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: During the Self regestration, which objects you are saving? have you written custom handler ?
Do you insert user and account and contact in  same transaction?